# {if}{else} do not work properly in smarty

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I have following smarty code on my template

```
{capture name="diff"}
    {datediff timestamp=$data_base.updated_date}
{/capture}

{$smarty.capture.diff} | {$smarty.const.UPDATE_BLOCK_SECONDS}

{if $smarty.capture.diff > $smarty.const.UPDATE_BLOCK_SECONDS}
    enable update
{else}
    disable update
{/if}
```

When I print both variable `$smarty.capture.diff` and `$smarty.const.UPDATE_BLOCK_SECONDS`, they output correct value (for example 98969 and 86400), but the {if} statement does not works and always print value "disable update"

Answer (score 4):

please try

```
{if 0+$smarty.capture.diff > 0+$smarty.const.UPDATE_BLOCK_SECONDS}
  enable update
{else}
  disable update
{/if}
```

or

```
{if (int)$smarty.capture.diff > (int)$smarty.const.UPDATE_BLOCK_SECONDS}
  enable update
{else}
  disable update
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{capture name="diff"}
    {datediff timestamp=$data_base.updated_date}
{/capture}
```

contains whitespace.

```
{capture name="diff"}{datediff timestamp=$data_base.updated_date}{/capture}
```

might be what you're looking for.

Comment: what I found is that `{(int)$smarty.capture.diff}` prints value 0 that's why it always return false. Still looking for a help to solve this issue :(